# How can I create a recurring event that spans multiple days in a Sharepoint 2010 calendar?

Tags: 2010, calendar, recurring-events

I am currently using a workaround where I create recurring events for each of the separate days in the event, but I would like to just create one recurring event that spans over 7 days. As is, the events show a separate visual block for each day, creating more visual noise than is desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

Recurring events that span multiple days are not supported in SharePoint 2010 Calendars.

To test I tried creating one with a SharePoint 2010 Calendar connected to Outlook 2010. On an Exchange Calendar in Outlook, I can create this type of recurring event. When performing the same creation activity on a Sharepoint calendar I received the following message:

> The recurrence pattern you selected for the current appointment is not
>   supported by SharePoint. Select another pattern or remove the
>   recurrence.

Comment: Note that no subsequent version of SharePoint supports this, either. Even in SharePoint Online this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another (tedious) workaround:

1. Create your event
2. Check **Recurrence**

   - Set your pattern
3. Set **Start Time** to the first day's start time
4. Set **End Time** to the last day's end time
5. **Save** the event series
6. For each event in the series:

   1. Click the event, click **Edit Item**
   2. Change **End Time** date to last day for that event's recurrence
   3. Click **Save**

This will create all the events in the series so they are manageable from a single event and change the events to better reflect its' time span.

**NOTE**: If you **Edit Series** after editing each item, those changes will not be reflected in each event. But you can **Delete** the entire series.

At least this way, you don't have to create a series for each day in the recurring event (managing separate series is annoying) and it gives the *single bar* look. A major drawback is if you have *a lot* of events to manually adjust.

I use this method to create a lot of similar events, but they span multiple days and they don't *exactly* fit the pattern set (e.g. Every 3rd Thurs except some months it needs to be the 2nd Thurs).

Comment: Might as well just create each item individually if you have to go back and touch each one to correct it, anyway. For creating something like an on-call calendar (which we can't do in Exchange because of issues due to ownership and employee turnover), this will be very tedious either way.